# Issues with Symfony 2.3 Web Debug Toolbar

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I'm in the process of upgrading old project from Symfony 2.1.x to 2.3.38, later I might try upgrading to latest LTS version. But first, I'd like to get it working at least on 2.3.

Here's the first hint, that something is wrong:

[image]

Code inspector shows that there are `<a>` blocks above two first buttons on toolbar, linking to _profile.

And clicking on any of toolbar items, to get inside debugger, ends up in routing error:

```
[3/3] Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No route found for "GET /my_project/web/_wdt/bdc9db"") in @WebProfiler/Profiler/layout.html.twig at line 5.
[2/3] NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /my_project/web/_wdt/bdc9db"
[1/3] ResourceNotFoundException
```

Maybe someone has encountered similar issues during upgrades? Any ideas how to debug this?

UPDATE:

Regarding the icons offset, looks like this was an issue with Symfony 2.3.38. I upgraded to 2.3.39 and icons are rendered correctly.
"No route found" issue still persist. _wdt is among the routes listed with app/route:debug.

UPDATE 2:

Finally found, that issue with "No route found" is related to sonata/cache-bundle package. If I remove it from AppKernel.php - everything works correctly. It also fixed issue I had with missing session data.

Comment: Did you looked at your `app/logs/dev.log` and apache logs ? Sometimes the toolbar crashes before the real error.

Comment: No critical errors, only few warnings about deprecation from Twig.

Answer (score 0):

Have You checked if Your app_dev.php is following changes made in 2.3LTS?

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.2/web/app_dev.php https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.3/web/app_dev.php

You have also documents about upgrading from previous versions (deprecations etc) called UPGRADE-X.X.md

Comment: Yes, that was first thing I did. Also, I installed standalone, clean version of Symfony, using the same updated composer.json file to check if it was working correctly, and it did.
This means problem is somewhere in custom code and/or additional bundles.